# Can I create a bootable Windows8.1 USB on a laptop running windows8.1 and use it to install it on a macbook pro?

Tags: mac, windows-8.1

Can I create a bootable Windows 8.1 USB pendrive on a laptop running Windows 8.1 and use it for installation on a Mac?

I have another product key for the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot.

Macs have no problems with running Windows 8.1.  The issue is the installation method.  You must install it from a DVD.  Macs will not boot anything other than OS X from a USB flash drive (at least not without significant hacks).  If this is a newer model iMac or Retina MacBook, you'll need to find an external USB DVD drive for it.

Answer (score 0):

So because of the way the Max BIOS works you can't boot off the flashdrive (I've at least never discovered an easy way to do it). What you CAN do, however, is use Bootcamp, which is included in MacOSX, and install Windows on that using a flash drive. Boot Camp is a utility for basically doing exactly what you want, except you can't format your hard drive (i.e., remove MacOSX) and install Windows on it. You can only partition it and install Windows on that partition.

http://www.howtogeek.com/186907/how-to-install-windows-on-a-mac-with-boot-camp/